# Joomla password hacked

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla2.5

It seems the admin password for my Joomla site is hacked. There was only one user, admin. I can't access the account. I tried the following via phpmyadmin in the _users table:

```
- admin  = 433903e0a9d6a712e00251e44d29bf87:UJ0b9J5fufL3FKfCc0TLsYJBh2PFULvT
- secret = d2064d358136996bd22421584a7cb33e:trd7TvKHx6dMeoMmBVxYmg0vuXEA4199
```

But it does not seem to work. I have access to the db and CPanel. There is a lot of data in articles etc. so I can't delete the database. The version is 2.5

How can I reset the password for the admin user ?

Regards !

Comment: [This guide](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_or_reset_your_admin_password%3F) has helped me a lot of times.

Comment: I tried all of these. But I think since I have a newer value for $secret than the default, these simple md5 hashes aren't working for me. I need to know how to generate a new hash that will work... :(

Comment: If you set up a fresh copy of Joomla on a subdomain, set the password for your admin account, then simply copy over the data from the "Password" column in the database to your original site.

Comment: This isn't a good question for Stackoverflow, you'd be better off on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com, — try this answer http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43200/joomla-2-5-password-to-backend-lost/43201#43201

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Access you phpmyadmin -> go to #__users table choose your admin user name.
Then update your password with this
08af319cdddbcac8d2949042a416ac61:447pZnWzKdAQ81R9kX4xNiPfZTM5JOwE
```

The above encrypted value is the password of 123456.

first you just update password in the DB then you will get access to admin panel.
There you can change your admin user password.
Users->users manager->edit

Hope this will works..

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the code where it hashes/encrypts (i'm goign to use hash from now on) your password. From there you should be able to pull out that code and create a new hashed password. Something like

```
var newpassword = 'mynewpassword';
var hashedpassword = hash(newpassword);//code from where you update your password
```

then update the hashedpassword into your database.

Comment: I have access to the config file. It has a variable public $secret. Can this help in getting a new hash ?

Comment: yes, you need to find where `$secret` is stored and reverse engineer everything. Then you can create a new hashed password.

Comment: I have found $secret. Please tell me how to generate a new password now using this

Comment: Did you try adding a root user in configuration.php?